# How to persist a file under NSHomeDirectory()?

Tags: ios, caching, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to implement cache function for my app.

In order to load the cache file each time the app launches, I store the cache file under `NSHomeDirectory()`. The code (C function) is as following:

```
NSString* getArchivePathForId(NSString* modelId)
{
    NSString *cacheIdentifier = @"CacheIdentifier";
    NSString *archiveDirPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/tmp/%@/cachedModel/%@", getAppVersion(), cacheIdentifier];

    NSError* error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:archiveDirPath]) {
        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:archiveDirPath
                                   withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:&error])
        {
            NSLog(@"Create directory tmp/cachedModel directory error: %@", error);
            return nil;
        }
    }

    NSString *archivePath = [archiveDirPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", modelId];
    return archivePath;
}
```

It works fine as long as the App is running or coming back to live from the background mode. But once the app is terminated and re-run, the cached archive file is deleted.

Is there any way to persist the archive file so that I can load the cache stored last time when the app was launched.

I have already realised that each time the app is launched, the application id part of the `NSHomeDirectory()` is different. Does this have anything to do with my issue?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the "tmp" directory name at the top level. Generally files are saved under the "Documents" directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];`
```

Persistent caches are generally placed under the "Library" directly, use `NSLibraryDirectory`.

See: [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

tmp/
Use this directory to write temporary files that do not need to persist between launches of your app. Your app should remove files from this directory when they are no longer needed; however, the system may purge this directory when your app is not running.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I should use `NSLibraryDirectory` instead of `NSHomeDirectory`, right? And what about the `Library/Caches/` directory mentioned in the link, should I put my cache files under this directory or just `Library/` directory?